# Non-Blocking Endpoint: Returning an operation ID to the caller - Would like to get your opinion on my implementation?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Boot Pros,

I recently started to program in spring-boot and I stumbled upon a question where I would like to get your opinion on.

**What I try to achieve:**

- I created a Controller that exposes a `GET` endpoint, named `nonBlockingEndpoint`. This `nonBlockingEndpoint` executes a pretty long operation that is resource heavy and can run between 20 and 40 seconds.(in the attached code, it is mocked by a `Thread.sleep()`)
- Whenever the `nonBlockingEndpoint` is called, the spring application should register that call and immediatelly return an Operation ID to the caller.
- The caller can then use this ID to query on another endpoint `queryOpStatus` the status of this operation. At the beginning it will be started, and once the controller is done serving the reuqest it will be to a code such as `SERVICE_OK`. The caller then knows that his request was successfully completed on the server.

**The solution that I found:**

- I have the following controller (note that it is explicitely **not** tagged with @Async)
- It uses an `APIOperationsManager` to register that a new operation was started
- I use the `CompletableFuture` java construct to supply the long running code as a new asynch process by using `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {}`
- I immdiatelly return a response to the caller, telling that the operation is in progress
- Once the Async Task has finished, i use `cf.thenRun()` to update the Operation status via the API Operations Manager

Here is the code:

```
    @GetMapping(path="/nonBlockingEndpoint")
public @ResponseBody ResponseOperation nonBlocking() {

    // Register a new operation
    APIOperationsManager apiOpsManager = APIOperationsManager.getInstance();
    final int operationID = apiOpsManager.registerNewOperation(Constants.OpStatus.PROCESSING);
    ResponseOperation response = new ResponseOperation();

    response.setMessage("Triggered non-blocking call, use the operation id to check status");
    response.setOperationID(operationID);
    response.setOpRes(Constants.OpStatus.PROCESSING);

    CompletableFuture<Boolean> cf = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {

        try {
            // Here we will 
            Thread.sleep(10000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

        // whatever the return value was
        return true;
    });
    cf.thenRun(() ->{ 
        // We are done with the super long process, so update our Operations Manager
        APIOperationsManager a = APIOperationsManager.getInstance();
        boolean asyncSuccess = false;

        try {asyncSuccess = cf.get();} 
        catch (Exception e) {}

        if(true == asyncSuccess) {
            a.updateOperationStatus(operationID, Constants.OpStatus.OK);
            a.updateOperationMessage(operationID, "success: The long running process has finished and this is your result: SOME RESULT" );
        } 
        else {
            a.updateOperationStatus(operationID, Constants.OpStatus.INTERNAL_ERROR);
            a.updateOperationMessage(operationID, "error: The long running process has failed."); 
        }
    });

    return response;
}
```

Here is also the APIOperationsManager.java for completness:

```
public class APIOperationsManager {

    private static APIOperationsManager instance = null;

    private Vector<Operation> operations;
    private int currentOperationId;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    protected APIOperationsManager() {}

    public static APIOperationsManager getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            synchronized(APIOperationsManager.class) {
                if(instance == null) {
                    instance = new APIOperationsManager();
                    instance.operations = new Vector<Operation>();
                    instance.currentOperationId = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }


    public synchronized int registerNewOperation(OpStatus status) {
        cleanOperationsList();

        currentOperationId = currentOperationId + 1;
        Operation newOperation = new Operation(currentOperationId, status);
        operations.add(newOperation);
        log.info("Registered new Operation to watch: " + newOperation.toString());
        return newOperation.getId();
    }

    public synchronized Operation getOperation(int id) {

        for(Iterator<Operation> iterator = operations.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Operation op = iterator.next();
            if(op.getId() == id) {
                return op;
            }
        }

        Operation notFound = new Operation(-1, OpStatus.INTERNAL_ERROR);
        notFound.setCrated(null);

        return notFound;
    }

    public synchronized void updateOperationStatus (int id, OpStatus newStatus) {

        iteration : for(Iterator<Operation> iterator = operations.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Operation op = iterator.next();
            if(op.getId() == id) {
                op.setStatus(newStatus);
                log.info("Updated Operation status: " + op.toString());
                break iteration;
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void updateOperationMessage (int id, String message) {

        iteration : for(Iterator<Operation> iterator = operations.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Operation op = iterator.next();
            if(op.getId() == id) {
                op.setMessage(message);
                log.info("Updated Operation status: " + op.toString());
                break iteration;
            }
        }
    }

    private synchronized void cleanOperationsList() {
        Date now = new Date();

        for(Iterator<Operation> iterator = operations.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Operation op = iterator.next();
            if((now.getTime() - op.getCrated().getTime()) >= Constants.MIN_HOLD_DURATION_OPERATIONS ) {
                log.info("Removed operation from watchlist: " + op.toString());
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The questions that I have**

- Is that concept a valid one that also scales? What could be improved?
- Will i run into concurrency issues / race conditions?
- Is there a better way to achieve the same in boot spring, but I just didn't find that yet? (maybe with the @Async directive?)

I would be very happy to get your feedback.

Thank you so much,
Peter P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a valid pattern to submit a long running task with one request, returning an id that allows the client to ask for the result later.

But there are some things I would suggest to reconsider :

- do not use an Integer as id, as it allows an attacker to guess ids and to get the results for those ids. Instead use a random UUID.
- if you need to restart your application, all ids and their results will be lost. You should persist them to a database.
- Your solution will not work in a cluster with many instances of your application, as each instance would only know its 'own' ids and results. This could also be solved by persisting them to a database or Reddis store.
- The way you are using CompletableFuture gives you no control over the number of threads used for the asynchronous operation. It is possible to do this with standard Java, but I would suggest to use Spring to configure the thread pool
- Annotating the controller method with @Async is not an option, this does not work no way. Instead put all asynchronous operations into a simple service and annotate this with @Async. This has some advantages :

  - You can use this service also synchronously, which makes testing a lot easier
  - You can configure the thread pool with Spring
- The /nonBlockingEndpoint should not return the id, but a complete link to the queryOpStatus, including id. The client than can directly use this link without any additional information.

Additionally there are some low level implementation issues which you may also want to change :

- Do not use Vector, it synchronizes on every operation. Use a List instead. Iterating over a List is also much easier, you can use for-loops or streams.
- If you need to lookup a value, do not iterate over a Vector or List, use a Map instead.
- APIOperationsManager is a singleton. That makes no sense in a Spring application. Make it a normal PoJo and create a bean of it, get it autowired into the controller. Spring beans by default are singletons.
- You should avoid to do complicated operations in a controller method. Instead move anything into a service (which may be annotated with @Async). This makes testing easier, as you can test this service without a web context

Hope this helps.

**Do I need to make database access transactional ?**

As long as you write/update only one row, there is no need to make this transactional as this is indeed 'atomic'.

If you write/update many rows at once you should make it transactional to guarantee, that either all rows are updated or none.

However, if two operations (may be from two clients) update the same row, always the last one will win.

Comment: Hi Stefan. Thank you so much for this awesome answer. It did not only help me with the actual problem at hand but also made me understand spring boot better.

Comment: I updated my code to your suggestions and made the APIOperationsManager a service and persisted the Operations in a database. Now that I have multiple services asking the APIOperationsManager to register/update Operations, however, I am not sure how concurrency is dealt with. In the APIOperationsManager service do I need to declare all the methods that change the operations database as "transactional" or are database operations atomic per default.